# UIsearchBar cancel button causing navigation bar unhidden

Tags: iphone, ios

I m working on a tab based application.In which when i click on a tab a search bar is shown with table View. i have kept the navigation bar is hidden in ViewDidLoad. But when i clicks on the cancel button of Uisearchbar then navigation bar becomes unhidden.please provide me any solution if you have.

Comment: Please show what code have you written....

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` and where you want to show the navigation bar again `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];`

or

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
  if ( viewController == rootController ) {
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
  } else if ( [navigationController isNavigationBarHidden] ) {
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
  }
}
```